# Calculate the average of the n-th number of elements in the column and repeat the calculations for a certain number of intervals in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with modifying part of the code. I already asked about this problem earlier. [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904330/calculate-the-average-of-the-n-th-number-of-elements-in-the-column-in-pandas). However, now I need to find the average several times.

An example of the original dataframe looks like this:

```
code scale   year  week   a     b     c
1111  -5    2017    15   68    68    19
1111  -4    2017    16   30    95    24
1111  -3    2017    17   21    15    94
1111  -2    2017    18   67    30    16
1111  -1    2017    19   10    13    13
1111   0    2017    20   26    22    18
1111   1    2017    21   NaN   NaN   NaN
1111   2    2017    22   NaN   NaN   NaN
1111   3    2017    23   NaN   NaN   NaN
1111   4    2017    24   NaN   NaN   NaN
1111   5    2017    25   NaN   NaN   NaN
1111   6    2017    26   NaN   NaN   NaN
2222  -5    2017    15   13    19    21
2222  -4    2017    16   24    95    23
2222  -3    2017    17   22    32    76
2222  -2    2017    18   21    30    12
2222  -1    2017    19   15    55    17
2222   0    2017    20   23    22    23
2222   1    2017    21   NaN   NaN   NaN
2222   2    2017    22   NaN   NaN   NaN
2222   3    2017    23   NaN   NaN   NaN
2222   4    2017    24   NaN   NaN   NaN
2222   5    2017    25   NaN   NaN   NaN
2222   6    2017    26   NaN   NaN   NaN
....
```

The interval of the scale may be different, but I know it in advance. And the calculation should start from the place where the scale = 0. In the example for each period from 1 to 6, I need to calculate the average using the previous value in the range from -5 to 0. And as before, use the new calculated value. The essence of the calculations is to calculate the average value for each unique position from the column `code` in the `scale` from -5 to 6. Although the interval is the same for all values in the column `code`, but the number of unique values can be different. So I wanted to write a loop for each interval from -5 to 6, but I can not. Also there remains the problem that the number of columns as `a, b, c` may be different. I need to apply for example this code for each interval from -5 to 6.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#data is your dataframe name
column_list = list(data.columns.values)[4:]
for column_name in column_list :
    column = data[column_name].values
    #converted pandas series to numpy series
    for index in xrange(0,column.shape[0]):
        #iterating over entries in the column
        if np.isnan(column[index]):
            column[index] = np.nanmean(column.take(range(index-5,index+1),mode='wrap'))
```

The result should look like this:

```
code scale   year  week   a     b     c
1111  -5    2017    15   68    68    19
1111  -4    2017    16   30    95    24
1111  -3    2017    17   21    15    94
1111  -2    2017    18   67    30    16
1111  -1    2017    19   10    13    13
1111   0    2017    20   26    22    18
1111   1    2017    21   37    41    31
1111   2    2017    22   32    36    33
1111   3    2017    23   32    26    34
1111   4    2017    24   34    28    24
1111   5    2017    25   28    28    25
1111   6    2017    26   32    30    27
2222  -5    2017    15   13    19    21
2222  -4    2017    16   24    95    23
2222  -3    2017    17   22    32    76
2222  -2    2017    18   21    30    12
2222  -1    2017    19   15    55    17
2222   0    2017    20   23    22    23
2222   1    2017    21   20    42    29
2222   2    2017    22   21    46    30
2222   3    2017    23   20    38    31
2222   4    2017    24   20    39    24
2222   5    2017    25   20    40    26
2222   6    2017    26   21    38    27
...
```

I would be very grateful for any help!

**UPD**  The column `code` contains the individual device code. The columns `a,b,c` shows the number of devices in each region in a certain week and year. The task is to predict the number of devices for each code in each region for future dates, using the mean of known values. The scale is needed for the convenience of calculation. For example, take the code `1111`. Take column `a`. Known values ​​on a `scale` in the range `(-5,0)`. For them, count the average for the cell where the scale is `1`. It will be `37`. For the next cell, take the values ​​where the scale is `(-4,1)`. In it, the value will be equal to `31.833`. And so on for all cells, where `scale` from `1` to `6`. And so for columns `a, b, c`. We take the following code `2222`. We do the same for him. Take the column `a`. For a cell where the scale is `1`, count the average for known values ​​(the `scale` is again from `-5` to `0`, but where `code` is `2222`). We get `19.66`.  And so on.
The number of lines for each unique code is the same (from `-5` to `6`). But there can be a lot of codes.

I hope I managed to better explain the problem.

Comment: Can you please reword this question?? it is very confusing, I cant follow how your getting to the output. Also, check the calculations for you output values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we'll need is a way to get a moving average -- I could be wrong, but I don't think there's a functionality in place to handle this in pandas (I suppose this may or may not be surprising considering pandas does have ewa() and rolling_mean() implemented).  Makes sense to me to use recursion here since it's not too deep.

```
def moving_average(data, window, periods_forward):
    """docs"""

    try:
        data.shape[1]
    except IndexError:
        import sys
        print("Data shape %s found. If there is only one sample please reshape the data using .reshape(-1, 1)." % data.shape)
        sys.exit()

    # Base case: Kill the recursion once we've created enough forward looks.
    if periods_forward == 0:
        return data
    else:
        data = np.concatenate([data, data[-window:, :].mean(axis=0).reshape(1,-1)])

    periods_forward -= 1
    return moving_average(data, window, periods_forward)


# Reset values in the dataframe.
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for code in df.code.unique():
    df.loc[df.code == code, columns] = moving_average(
        df.loc[df.code == code, columns].dropna().values, window=6, periods_forward=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data looks the same as the sample provided, you could just do this

```
colSelector = df.columns.values[4:]

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if np.isnan(row[4:].values).any():
        col = colSelector[np.isnan(row[4:].values)]
        df.loc[index,col] = np.round(df.loc[index-6:index,col].mean(),0)
```

I assumed that you may have more columns to average than just a,b, and c, but this works either way. Also, instead of looping over each column, we can do some Boolean indexing to find the `NaN` values and choose to average them instead, thus eliminating the first loop.

Note: if it is just columns a-c and there is really data after those columns that are not to be average, change all `[4:]` to `[4:7]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Only I had a problem. It seems to me that the code should work. But when I run it, I get an error 
`IndexError: in the future, 0-d boolean arrays will be interpreted as a valid boolean index` on the line `col = colSelector[np.isnan(row[4:].values).any()][0]`
  I can not figure out what to do. Can you help, please?

Comment: @YanaDolyuk, I updated. There shouldn't have been `.any()` or `[0]` at the end, but I think you should update numpy to the most recent build also, since this was an error from a previous version.